# Review audit failed: very broad question

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently came across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19920226) in the VLQ review queue.

After having read it a few times, I thought it was too broad for the scope of SO. The user asked a very open-ended question, did not include any details about what they've tried so far (only what issues they've run into) and ended the post with

> Would love to hear your ideas/thoughts...

Any question containing this automatically makes my mind drift towards "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based".

Turns out, the question got six upvotes and three favorites and was considered a high-quality question, and I'm currently reviewbanned for two days.

I checked the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50576494/8343610) given, which pretty much confirms my initial thought that it was too broad/opinion-based, as the answer talks about how *their company* has implemented something and writes a full tutorial step-by-step on how they did it. (and the answer is not even accepted)

I have downvoted the question to stop it from appearing in audits because I feel like it's questionable at the least, but I have refrained from flagging it, because the failed audit made me question my action. Should I still flag it, or have I done wrong and should I wait for the reviewban to pass?

Comment: `What can you recommend [...]?` This is clearly an opinion-based question, and also too broad. I would also have VTC. This audit should be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, and getting the STOP! LOOK! LISTEN! hysterics thrown at you in such cases sort of stinks, eh....

Comment: The audit is working as intended. The question had a score of 6 without downvotes nor closevotes. If anything, the real question is why it got 7 upvotes.

Comment: Isn't every question in the VLQ queue an audit???

Comment: @AndréKool Yes, nowadays every question in the LQP queue is an audit.

Comment: Well, this one has been settled. But we should probably keep an eye on the [tag:angular] tag's "health".

Comment: The OP has right, and a false audit is obviously an exceptional case, thus it can't be a duplicate.

Comment: I've had a better look at the duplicate target and noticed some misunderstanding on whether the consequences of failing a bad audit should be undone or simply "tolerated". Is this concern left unsolved? Can't we _really_ request a moderator to lift the review ban in this particular case?

Comment: Yeah, this was clearly a bad audit. I had a quick skim of your review history, and your reviewing looks fine. I've lifted your review ban.

Comment: @Rob But shouldn't there be a few more bad reviews by him that he got banned?

Comment: @KamiKaze Yes, that's why Rob reviewed OPs history before lifting the ban

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question has been downvoted to oblivion, closed and even deleted, so it *should* not appear in any audits again. The review ban has been lifted by a moderator, after a review history scan to determine whether my reviewing was adequate. This issue has been resolved, thank you Rob.

Comment: Downvoted questions are blocked from being known-good audit candidates. They can and do, however, appear as known-bad, highly-voted questions audits (where a question is made to look like it has 10 upvotes but in reality it is closed and downvoted, or deleted).

Comment: @TylerH in LQRQ, the only known bad post are spam